# How to set icons for all TabBarItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm new to iOS, but I will try to explain what is my problem.

So I have, Navigation controller, TabBar Controller, and in TabBar Controller I have three viewcontroller.

So in the tab bar, I have three tabbarIcon.

Programmatically I set icons for tab bar items in their view controllers, in viewdidload method. So yes I know that when I  will start my application, icons will not load because it needs to call viewdidload.
So...

How can I set icons for all tabbarItem automatically, when the application will start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab bar items should be configured in the `init` or `awakeFromNib`' functions of your view controllers, not in `viewDidLoad` as the tab bar has already been displayed before this is called.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that when application will start as below:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];


tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1_selected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2_selected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];


tabBarItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3_selected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
```

Comment: The view controller should be responsible for configuring its own tab bar item. This will lead to more maintainable code.